# Why doesn't date subtraction produce whole numbers when casting TIMESTAMP to DATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, oracle-apex, date-arithmetic

Normal date subtraction looks like this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('12-29-2019') - TO_DATE('12-20-2019') FROM DUAL

/* RESULT: 9 */
```

When I cast a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE`, Oracle truncates the hours/minutes/seconds and produces a "whole" `DATE` value.

```
SELECT CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM DUAL

/* RESULT: 12/07/2019 */
```

But when performing date subtraction with a `CAST` from a `TIMESTAMP`, I don't get whole numbers anymore.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('12-29-2019') - CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM DUAL

/* RESULT: 21.0999421296296296296296296296296296296 */
```

Why doesn't date subtraction produce whole numbers when casting TIMESTAMP to DATE in Oracle?

Comment: `TO_DATE('12-29-2019')` is poor, either use ANSI literals (i.e. `DATE '2019-12-09'`) or specify the format: `TO_DATE('12-29-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy')`. Otherwise Oracle takes current `nls_date_format` which may change at any time.

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed. In Oracle both `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components; the `TIMESTAMP` data type can additionally have fractional seconds and time zone components. `CAST( LOCALTIMESTAMP AS DATE )` just removes the fractional seconds and time zone; it does not truncate the hour, minute and second components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because what you see is not what you have.

This was your command and result:

```
SQL> SELECT CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM DUAL;

CAST(LOC
--------
07.12.19
```

But, that's just because date format was set as such.

If you *alter session* and set different format, then you get

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS DATE) FROM DUAL;

CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP
-------------------
07.12.2019 22:44:47

SQL>
```

which is quite different, is it not? And that's why you got decimal number as a result. `TRUNC` it first to remove time component.